# ¿Cómo personalizar errores de base de datos sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, excepciones

quisiera saber cómo personalizar los errores obtenidos al intentar insertar en una tabla de sql server, por ejemplo:

```
 array:5 [▼
  0 => "HY000"
  1 => 20018
  2 => "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.users' with unique 
 index 'users_email_unique'. The duplicate key value is (ana@email.com). 
 [20018] (severity 14) [insert into [users] ([id_role], [name], [last_name], 
 [rut_user], [password], [email], [telefono1], [telefono2], [created_at], 
 [updated_at], [est_user]) values ('3', 'ana', 'dcds', '1222222', 
 '$2y$10$O7haIwQh9v8FH0h6bTm9ruduOxCtk8ciFg0Rz4FeHZwDCdTbnAGem', 
  'ana@email.com', '9632587', '5465465456', NULL, NULL, 1)] ◀"
 3 => -1
 4 => 14
]
```

El asunto es que todos los campos que estén duplicados lanza el mismo error "20018" y quiero poder escribir en la vista "correo duplicado" o "ci duplicado"

Agradezco los aportes

(si, intenté hacerlo con ajax pero no quiero llenar mi formulario de "botones validar" ya que los eventos de perder el foco del input no me funcionan)

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil si lanzas una consulta antes de insertar? y le avisas si ya existe

Comment: Deberías detectar el error antes de realizar la consulta SQL. Mencionas que las validaciones no te ayudaron, qué es lo que quieres validar? pues se pueden crear reglas de validación personalizadas.

Comment: Si, agregue con el ejemplo                                                                   
                    $v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'    => 'required|email|unique:clients',
          ]);      pero, por ejemplo en el campo email siempre me muestra el error "requerido" no importa que esté lleno, cuando debería mostrar que está repetido, le quité el required y lo dejé con boostrap y entonces no muestra nada

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví (de la mejor manera que encontré ya que con las validaciones de laravel no me resultó como quería)

Publico mi solución por si alguien lo llegara a necesitar:::

en el controlador:

```
try {

        if($usuario->save()){
            //dd($usuario); 
            Session::flash('message', 'Información guardada exitosamente!'); 
            return Redirect::to('/usuarios');
        }

    }catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){

        $error = $this->errores($e->getMessage());
        Session::flash('error', $error); 
        return Redirect::to('usuarios/create')->withInput()->with('id_role',$request['id_role']);

    } 


public function errores($error){

    $parcial = array();
    $mensaje = array();

    $parcial[0] = "UNIQUE KEY constraint 'AK_Rut'";
    $mensaje[0] = "Rut Repetido";
    $parcial[1] = "unique index 'users_email_unique'";
    $mensaje[1] = "Email repetido";

    $fin = count($parcial);
    for($i= 0; $i < $fin; $i++){
        $posicion_coincidencia = strpos($error, $parcial[$i]);
        if ($posicion_coincidencia != false) {
            return $mensaje[$i];
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya vi que solucionaste de la mejor manera que pudiste, pero por si alguien más lo necesita lo publicare. Así lo fuera hecho yo, esta es mi solución:

```
BEGIN TRY
    --SELECT 1/0;
    INSERT INTO [Cod_ProdFarm] ([id_role], [name], [last_name], [rut_user], [password], 
    [email], [telefono1], [telefono2], [created_at], [updated_at], [est_user])
    VALUES ('3', 'ana', 'dcds', '1222222', '$2y$10$O7haIwQh9v8FH0h6bTm9ruduOxCtk8ciFg0Rz4FeHZwDCdTbnAGem', 
    'ana@email.com', '9632587', '5465465456', NULL, NULL, 1);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 2601 OR ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Email Repetido' AS ErrorMessage;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END
END CATCH;
```